# Accurate control with \setupalign[hanging] for optical margins in ConTeXt?

Tags: margins, context, hyphenation, optical

How could I get more control handling the "hanging" option for hyphenation with optical margins provided by \setupalign[hanging]? That is to say, I am not worried about protrusion. The default "hz" option of ConTeXt is enough for me. I know that there is no accounting for taste, but "hanging" seems to me visually good with the hyphens of some fonts, and not so good whit others.

The default internal settings from simply "hanging" may be good for many but not for my aesthetic preferences.

> For me, it is only a point about tastes with the displacement towards the margins, but only with the hyphenation glyphs. I am speaking all the time about the hyphenations, not about the hold protrusion.

[image]

This is too much projection towards the right margin in my opinion. But, anyway, I insist: I know that are different strokes for different folks.

Apart from that, the protrusion within the lines is fine for my tastes.

Comment: It might help to define what you consider "flexible" and provide an example that illustrates "counter-productive" results and how it "wrecks" the advantages. I assume you probably looked at it already, but the Wiki page (http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Protrusion) does highlight some options like hz adjustments.

Comment: You can define your own protrusion vectors in Lua, see “8.8 Protrusion” in [Fonts out of ConTeXt](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/fonts-mkiv.pdf).  To me it's not really clear what you are asking.  Do you have a concrete example where you think default settings for protrusion fail and a clear vision of what it should be instead?

Comment: @ebohoyod You should elaborate what “many times it looks too much marked” means, supported by an example.  Otherwise the answer to your question “Is there any tweak...?” is simply “Yes.”  Those kinds of yes-no questions are generally discouraged on this site, see [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: @HenriMenke, you can not see in my question anything about me suggesting that "default settings for protrusion fail" like you have said. For me, it is only a point about taste with the displacement towards the external margins, but only with the hyphenation glyphs. I am speaking all the time about the hyphenations, not about protrusion.

Comment: @HenriMenke. You are right.  I will post an example. Thanks.

Comment: @ssokolen, thanks for your advice. I am very happy with my hz adjustments. My problem is about the excessive (for my tastes) projected space towards the right margins with the hyphenations glyphs. I have upgraded an example with Sukhumala font.

Comment: Ah, I see your problem.  It is unfortunate that the protrusion settings are defined in terms of the em-width of the font, because when the hyphen is rather short compared to the em-width you get this effect of extreme hanging.  But as for any font-related dimension, one size never fits all.

Comment: @HenriMenke, thanks. That resolves the matter. I will try to be more concise and graphically explicit in the future.

Comment: @ebohoyod Did my answer solve your problem?  If not, please explain where you find it to be lacking.

Comment: @HenriMenke, I voted you on Jul 25. Why are you asking me this? Like I wrote just above on that date, your answer solved my problem. Thanks again.

Comment: @ebohoyod Ah, I see, thank you.  Usually, on this site, when an answer solves your problem, you mark it as [accepted answer](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓ next to the score).

Comment: @HenriMenke Thanks again. Now, my question is formally solved ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As outlined in “8.8 Protrusion” in [Fonts out of ConTeXt](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/fonts-mkiv.pdf) you can easily construct your own protrusion vectors.  Here I use the `quality` vector but change the protrusion settings for the hyphen (default of the `punctuation` vector which is used by the `quality` vector is `{ 0, 0.70 }`)

```
\startluacode
fonts.protrusions.vectors.ebohoyod = table.merged(
    fonts.protrusions.vectors.quality,
    {
        [0x002D] = { 0, 0.25 }, -- hyphen
    }
)
\stopluacode
\setupfontprotrusion[ebohoyod][vector=ebohoyod]

\definefontfeature
  [quality]
  [default]
  [protrusion=quality]

\definefontfeature
  [ebohoyod]
  [default]
  [protrusion=ebohoyod]

\definefont[First][file:Sukhumala-Regular.otf*quality]
\definefont[Second][file:Sukhumala-Regular.otf*ebohoyod]

\setupalign[hanging]

\starttext

\startoverlay
  {\ruledvbox{\color[gray]{\First\input knuth\par}}}
  {\ruledvbox{\Second\input knuth\par}}
\stopoverlay

\stoptext
```

In the background is the original `quality` protrusion setting (light gray).  Maybe 0.25 is too little margin kerning...

[image]